# how do i do Marquee stop Delay for each text line

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, marquee

Good day

What i want to do is that:

```
Headlines ...........
```

imagine that the text scrolls down and stops each time for a specific delay then resume its scroll for a next text line

how do i do that? i found a hover in http://jsfiddle.net/BM2Cq/ that stops when you hover above the text.

i also want to incorporate the hover too :)

heres the code what i got for now:

```
<marquee class="tracks_marquee" direction="down" height="28" scrollamount="3" >Headline Text</marquee>
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        (".tracks_marquee").hover(function()
                                   {
                                       $(this).attr("scrollamount","0");
                                       $(this).start();

                                   },
                                   function()
                                   {
                                       $(this).attr("scrollamount","2");                                             $(this).stop();
                                   })


                  })
```

so thanks :D

Comment: You would be better off getting a purpose built script instead of trying to hack something that was proprietary not so long ago. Jquery cycle for example

Comment: do you know where would i get something like that? im not familiar in jquery >.<

Comment: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

did you mean like using attribute scrolldelay

ex : 
< marquee scrolldelay=5> Scrolling Text with delay < /marquee>

Comment: That does nothing in Chrome